# Colapso no cabeçalho com javascript puro

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Gostaria de fazer um cabeçalho que ao descer a barra de rolagem, ele comprima seu conteúdo. Tenho o seguinte *script* até agora.

```
window.scroll(function() {
    var scroll = window.scrollTop();
    var element = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (scroll >= 140) {
        element.classList.add("rola");
    } else {
        element.classList.remove("rola");;
    }
});
```

Sei que os componentes `HTML` são carregados depois do objeto `window`, então como procederia com o *script*? Não sei como fazer para esperar que o componente seja carregado.

Comment: Você pode utilizar `window.onscroll = function() { /* Code Here */ }`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a documentação na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll), a função `window.scroll` recebe dois parâmetros, x e y, e não uma função *callback*, tal como fez. Acredito que o que você deseja fazer é *ouvir* o evento de *scroll* e executar a função sempre a página for rolada. Para isso, utilize o evento [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/scroll) de `window`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    ...
});
```

Mas esse evento será disparado muitos vezes quando a página for rolada, então tome muito cuidado com a performance.